# I am questioning how this code compiled even though struct iwreq does not have ifr_name as a member

Tags: c, linux, wifi, wireless

I wrote very simple code using struct iwreq.
Also, I expected this will be error.
But it is compiled and works.

I looked inside linux/wireless.h which has the definition of struct iwreq.
And the iwreq does not ifr_name as a member.

Would someone can give me an idea?
Here is the simple code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <linux/wireless.h>

int main(void)
{
   char *intf = "eth0";
   struct iwreq iwr;

   strncpy(iwr.ifr_name, intf, sizeof(iwr.ifr_name));

   printf("main : intf = %s, iwr.ifr_name = %s\n", intf, iwr.ifr_name);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably you looked at some other header for the definition. Where is this code from? Why did you use these names in the first place?

Comment: What does `printf '#include <linux/wireless.h>\n@@@ ifr_name\n' | gcc -E -P -xc - | grep @@@` print?

Comment: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/if.h#L259

Answer (score 2):

`wireless.h` includes `if.h`, and inside `if.h` you can find:

```
#define ifr_name    ifr_ifrn.ifrn_name  /* interface name   */
```

So the code is translated to:

```
strncpy(iwr.ifr_ifrn.ifrn_name, intf, sizeof(iwr.ifr_ifrn.ifrn_name));
```

Comment: you dropped the ifr_ifrn part

Comment: @zwol oops, right ;)

Answer (score 1):

/usr/include/linux/wireless.h includes linux/if.h:

```
#include <linux/if.h>           /* for IFNAMSIZ and co... */
```

And in /usr/include/linux/if.h there is:

```
#define ifr_name    ifr_ifrn.ifrn_name  /* interface name   */
```